# How can I automatically load the Google Style Rules to SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube

I have found this xml with style rules: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml  .

I would like to save developers time from manually flagging non-conformities by loading the list into SonarQube but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of loading the rules (you'd have to write a plugin for that) consider just loading the issues. The [Generic Issue Data](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Issue+Data) feature was added recently (7.2) for just that case.

**Edit:** Current [docs here](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/importing-external-issues/generic-issue-import-format/)

Comment: The link is now broken :(

Comment: Thanks for the ping @Zymotik. New link added